Error during deploying through render: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/run'
My github for the same: https://github.com/Sam-Gaming/InstagramClone
error: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/run'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
This is an error i am getting when i'm trying to deploy my project onto render. I am not able to understand why this is happening
Y am i not able to deploy it, please explain the error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
